# How to launch an app when a 5 touch gesture occures

Tags: android, homescreen, lockscreen

Does any one have any suggestions on how to launch an app when the device senses a 5 touch gesture on either the home or locked screen? I am working on building an app that will sense whenever a home screen or lock screen is touched by 5 touches at once and send the exact coords of the 5 points to the app. Any help on this would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, unless you are the author of the homescreen in question.

Comment: Alright that is what I was afraid of but I wanted to be sure. What if it was a custom Lock Screen app? I have seen those before. Any ideas?